# How start to UITextView from paragraph in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

How to start a new line in `UITextView` with a little space, called paragraph I believe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make the controller confront to UITextFieldDelegate

for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate 
{
   //link the textfield
   @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // link the delegate to the textfield
      textField.delegate = self   
   }

    //this function detects the return button when it's pressed

   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
   {
    //since we always want to start a new line with space we override the default function

     textField.text += "\n "
     return false
}
```